# Windows Server 2016 ignores overclock

Tags: overclocking, windows-server-2016

I've had a stable overclock for over a year now under various installations of W10. I just installed Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and suddenly everytime I boot into windows, the CPU won't go higher than the default 3.5GHz. I would get over this but it won't even get the default TurboBoost of 3.9GHz.

Suspecting some sort of bad reporting, I ran a couple of benchmarks and it really seems to be stuck at 3.5GHz max.
The OC is set in BIOS, regular stuff.

Is there some policy setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the default "Balanced" power plan. Changing the plan to "High performance" let the processor achieve the max speed and further changing the "Advanced power settings" entry for "Minimum processor state" to the lowest possible value (5%) allowed it to use lower frequencies when idle.

Comment: You forgot to put the check mark beside the answer. There is a gray check mark symbol. Click on it so that becomes green.

Comment: @FleetCommand you can't accept you're own answer [until 48 hours after posting.](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Huh! That's new!

Comment: @FleetCommand - Actually....It's not.